Write bash autocomplete for executing executables found in directory tree
I want to get bash autocompletion to work whenever I want to start an executable, e.g. I want to execute
./build/test/auto/ProviderTester(.exe)

but I only want to type
./

and bash should give me completions based on all the executables it finds in the below directory hierarchy. Is this possible? My end goal is to combine this with fzf to give me a list of all executables that I can interactively select.
Note: The problem is that complete -F __compl_foo './' doesn't work, since I belive ./ is not recognised as a command. Bash will however also do default completions for ./ but is there a way to verwrite this behaviour?

Use find (or any alternative, e.g. fd), filter for executables, and feed that into fzf. Bind that to a key to invoke it.

@pmf Yes I already wrote parts like this, but I can't figure out how to make bash autocomplete on ./ which is not a real command in that sense.

You're looking for something like this:
__compl_foo()
  case $2 in */)
    COMPREPLY=(
      $(compgen -c $2)
      $(find $2 ! -type d -executable)
    )
  esac

complete -I -F __compl_foo -o bashdefault


Nice it works, I tweaked it a little bit. Why are you using compgen additionally to find though? And could you explain the -I flag to complete a little bit?

@glades So it returns what it would normally return along with what find finds. The manual explains the -I flag very well.

I feel I have the wrong manual. What's your source? Mine is https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html
